# How to correctly use the z-transformation in deriving the normal pdf from the binomial

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I have understood that the Normal distribution may be motivated by considering the Binomial distribution for large N. I wished to create a geogebra file but encountered a problem I'd not thought of before.

Specifically let $X\sim B(n,p)$ then, for large values of $n$, both the mean $\mu=np$ and the variance $\sigma^2=np(1-p)$ become large too.

The above suggests a transformation $z=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}$ so that the mean is centred at the origin and the distribution has constant spread of 1.

Note that $P_x=P(X=x)=\binom nxp^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ for the binomial distribution.
So as $\Sigma P_x=1 $ we could examine a function $f(z)$ designed so that $ f(z)=\frac{P_x}{\Delta z }$ and therefore $\Sigma f(z)\Delta z=1$
If we consider the limit of $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta z}$ as $n\to \infty, \Delta z \to 0$ we can form a simple differential equation and recover the Normal PDF.

When I tried to put this into practice it dawned on me that $P_x$ would only hold for positive integers yet surely Z would take non integer values?  I believe the above transformation is correct but would like further clarity.
I have considered changing $\binom nx$ to $\frac{\Gamma(n) }{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(n-z)}$ is this correct?

I ultimately wanted to show the "sticks" for the binomial getting closer and approximating an area in geogebra.  I hope that makes sense.  Thanks for any assistance.  I would appreciate simpler-ish answers if possible (I know my limits!)

Comment: (1) Don't forget the $\mu$ term in the z-transformation.  (2) And remember that $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!,$ not $n!.$  Thus $\binom{n}{x}=\Gamma(n+1)/(\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(n-x+1)).$ (3) Finally, notice that "$x$" appears on both sides of (2): "$z$" doesn't belong there at all. (4) If the "sticks" are bars in a bar chart, you have a problem because you need to convert *height* to *area.*  It might be clearer and easier to start with a histogram rather than a bar chart.

Comment: @Karl If you want to show the distribution converging, you might be better to look at the behaviour of the distribution function (the *cdf*) rather than try to deal with a discrete pmf.